# How to get single quoted words from string using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

i have string looks like

```
[Department] = 'Accounts' Or [Department] = 'HR'
```

I need to extract the string content between ' ' (single quotes). ie here the expected output is

Accounts
HR

How i can do this by using regular expression. Here i am listing sample input and outputs

```
Input                                                             Output

[Department] = 'Accounts' Or [Department] = 'HR'                  Accounts, HR
[Department] In ('Accounts', 'HR', 'IT')                          Accounts, HR, IT
[Department] = 'IT'                                               IT
```

If it is difficulty to do with regular expression, how i can do this by using some substring /split methode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'([^']*)'
```

This should do it.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/bZ8aY1/3